# How to bring a React Native Android app to the foreground when it is in the background or has been killed?

Tags: java, android, react-native

Is there any way to bring a React Native app to the foreground when it is in the background or has been killed?

I have tried using [react-native-invoke-app](https://github.com/vicke4/react-native-invoke-app) but it is no longer being maintained and only supports Android versions < 9.

Answer (score 3):

I think the best way to do this is to set a URL scheme and opening the URL connected to the app.

**1 - Add this line of code**

`<data android:scheme="my-awesome-app" />` in `./android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` under the `<intent-filter>` under `<activity>` tag.

This will give a scheme to your app which is useful in deepLinking and opening your app with a browser or while you're in other apps.
Actually if you open the `my-awesome-app://` url, you're app will be opened.

**2 - Write a headless task or an event listener to run `Linking.openURL(my-awesome-app://);`**

This is an example from `react-native-firebase` message listener.

```
import firebase from 'react-native-firebase';
import {Linking} from 'react-native';

firebase.messaging().onMessage((message) => {
    // Process your message as required
    Linking.openURL('my-awesome-app://')
  });
}
```

To set the URL scheme setting on iOS, you must add it in URL types in `info.plist` file like the picture below.

[image: iOS setting up URL scheme]

Comment: Have you tried this solution?

Comment: yes @iRohitBhatia

Comment: Hi, I have tried this solution. But the app can't be opened on Android.

Comment: Anyone comes here and cant resolve this. Create another <intent-filter> and ad your  <data ... /> to there
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/19928#issuecomment-463971415